# Android XML: drawing StackOverflow's GraphicDesign's diamond/rhombus button with diamond/rhombus borders

Tags: android, android-widget, android-button, android-styles

I would want to use the same borders than this button: [image] (cf.: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). Is it possible to use the `radius` XML properties (`borderLeftTopRadius`, etc.) to do it? Or must I use some image(s)?

Comment: You can do this by drawing the line as vector drawable: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources

Comment: Your best bet is to create a vector image or a 9-patch image. There's a nice generator for 9-patch assets [here](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a Drawable resource file : custom_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="153.77dp"
android:height="41.33dp"
android:viewportWidth="153.77"
android:viewportHeight="41.33">

<path
    android:strokeColor="#e94b5a"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:strokeMiterLimit="10"
    android:pathData="M 9.89 0.5 L 144.22 0.5 L 153.22 20.5 L 144.22 40.83 L 10.22 
40.83 L 0.55 20.5 L 9.89 0.5 Z" />
</vector>
```

then put it as background of your button :

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ask question"
    android:textColor="#E94A5A"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"/>
```

Screenshot :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBjH4.png)

Comment: I didn't knew `path`, thank you! Any suggestion for these improvements: supporting the material input events like click on the button, to colour the clicked surface of the button?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using Vectors. It is available in android studio. Click on this link for more information. [Add multi-density vector graphics](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio)

The default android xml code only will help you achieve rounded corners and dashed borders with some gradient.